# How to copy and paste from cell in C1FlexGrid?

Tags: c#, events, copy-paste, componentone, c1flexgrid

I want to copy and paste from one cell to another / C1FlexGrid
copy from selected red cell and paste other value here - shown image

copy from selected red cell/ Image is here

[image]

Is there any event like `KeyDown` etc

Any example code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events **KeyDown/KeyPress/KeyUp** wont work in this case since your FlexGrid is in edit mode. When in edit mode try using **KeyDownEdit/KeyPressEdit/KeyUpEdit** events for the FlexGrid.

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub C1FlexGrid1_KeyPressEdit(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEditEventArgs)
Handles c1FlexGrid1.KeyPressEdit
    'Implement logic here
End Sub
```

**C#:**

```
public Form1()
    {
        this.c1FlexGrid1.KeyPressEdit += new KeyPressEditEventHandler(this.c1FlexGrid1_KeyPressEdit);
    }

    private void c1FlexGrid1_KeyPressEdit(object sender, KeyPressEditEventArgs e)
    {
       // Implement logic here
    }
```

However, I would suggest you to use **ValidateEdit** event to implement your use case.

Comment: Hi, it's working. One more question how can I **paste** in edit mode, and CTR+A to select all? Thank you.

Comment: @AliSilamkhanDvR Can you elaborate your use-case? I think you might implement this using any other event

Comment: Ok, I did it by using 'IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();' to getdata PASTE :-)